# Pig Latin: All pairs within a group - Nested foreach with a cross and filter

Tags: apache-pig

I have some grouped data:

```
glu: (
    group:tuple(foo:bytearray, bar:chararray),
    bam: bag {
        :tuple(foo:bytearray, bar:chararray, pom:Long)
    }
)
```

What I want is to do a nested cross-product to get all pairs of pom, and a filter to reduce to only pairs where the first pom is less than the second pom. Ending up with something like this:

```
glu: (
    group:tuple(foo:bytearray, bar:chararray),
    bam: bag {
        :tuple(foo:bytearray, bar:chararray, pom1:Long, pom2:Long)
    }
)
```

something like:

```
glupairs = FOREACH glu {
    pairs = CROSS bam, bam;
    filtered = FILTER pairs BY (bam1 != bam2) AND (bam1 < bam2);
    GENERATE group, filtered;
};
```

This, of course, does not work.  Is there a way to do this?  Can I take a cross product of a relation against itself? how can I select the fields afterwards (to do the filter)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out by doing:

```
glupairs = FOREACH glu {
    copied = FOREACH bam GENERATE -(-pom); -- Deals with the self cross bug
    pairs = CROSS bam, copied;
    filtered = FILTER pairs BY (bam.pom != copied.pom) AND (bam.pom < copied.pom);
    GENERATE group, filtered;
};
```